# Benchmarking MS SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, benchmark

We have several production SQL servers, some physical, some virtual.  I would really like some generic scripts that I could run against each maybe using AdventureWorks to stress test them and compare the performance.

Does anyone know of anything which is commonly used?  I understand that different types of load (e.g OLTP, DW) require different hardware but I need something to get started in order to give some accurate comparisons between the different environments.

Comment: So are these production servers already in production or will you be putting them into production in the near future?

Comment: They're already in production.  I would like to make a case for improved hardware.  Simple stats like this 4-cpu VM is 50% slower than the 8-way physical for this type of query (which I will translate to business speak)

Answer (score 0):

Wond work.

> run against each maybe using AdventureWorks

Pathetic database. WAY too small for real word testing. Waht you want to test in particular?

There are tests, but they require a lot of hardware.

In general, I do a good SQLIO test, plus you can do some cpu based tests. That is about it.

Comment: I'm not hung up on AdventureWorks, just after something with some credibility / well know.  How are you doing a 'good SQLIO test' ?

Comment: Using SQLIO. Big enough file to be 4-8 times ram.

Comment: Since these servers are actually in production, I would recommend running SQLIO only during a maintenance window, as it could impact performance on these servers.

Comment: Absolutely. But this is the only way to measure how fast you CAN go - no load, and see how far you go.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to get some baseline stats on your servers, I would recommend starting with Perfmon counters.  Brent Ozar has an excellent tutorial here: [SQL Server Perfmon Counters Tutorial](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2006/12/dba-101-using-perfmon-for-sql-performance-tuning/)

These stats are great for identifying bottlenecks, trending usage (when you run multiple times), identifying servers you may wish to consolidate, etc.